# How to combine one terminal command in Concourse task run config

Tags: concourse, concourse-task

How shall I combine one terminal command in Concourse task

command I use on terminal

`export ENVIRONMENT=development NODE_ENV=local; mvn clean install`

How to use this in Concourse run config? Are below lines correct?

```
run:
            path: /usr/bin/mvn
            dir: pr
            args:
              - -exc
              - |
              - export
                  ENVIRONMENT = development
                  NODE_ENV= local
              - clean 
              - install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly run the command as a shell command

```
run:
   path: /bin/sh
   dir: pr
   args:
    - -exc
    - |
      export ENVIRONMENT=development NODE_ENV=local
      mvn clean install
```

Else, the variables being exported must be set under `params` in task config before `run`

```
params:
  ENVIRONMENT: development
  NODE_ENV: local
run:
  path: /usr/bin/mvn
  dir: pr
  args: 
   - clean
   - install
```